# How do I convert a Bundle's object to json where there is no key

Tags: android, json, object, bundle, android-bundle

I have a bundle that has an object in it. normally you have key value pairs but the entire bundle is a representation of an object

ie

Bundle[{id=39, special_requests=, definition_id=2562}]

this is a simplified version because there are a lot of object properties

So basically the first and only value of the bundle is an object, how can i extract it with out a key?

Comment: Spidy is correct - you can't have a value in a Bundle without it having a key.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options with an object. If the object implements [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), then you can get it with `getParcelable(KEY)`. Otherwise, you must use `getSerializable(KEY)` . No matter what though, it will have a key. You cannot put something in a Bundle without a key.